# Hibernate: How to lazy load entire level of detail after parent entity already loaded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say a List has already been loaded from the database.  Each A has one to many Bs.  Is there a way I can load all the Bs in one query, and have Hibernate apply them to the related A by keys?  Essentially, a lazy-load, but one that spans multiple objects (albeit related ones) and get applied to those objects correctly?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think hibernate let you do this. One thing you can do is write your own query to load the Bs : `select b from B b where b.a in (:listA)`

Then you can manually set the Bs in each A.

Another solution is to join fetch the Bs when you load the As, but maybe it's not a solution for you.